# Battery Protection IC (DW06D) burning LDO (MCP1700)

Tags: pcb, esp8266, lipo, ldo, over-voltage-protection

I badly need your help.
I have a PIR sensor setup. It works fine without the DW06D LiPo battery protection IC.

Yesterday I added the battery protection IC (instead of just bypassing it) since the DW06D took some time to ship. This is U1 in my schematic.
The moment I inserted the 18650 battery, the LDO started emitting smoke and burnt.

I then made a small board to test the DW06D, everything worked as expected and combined with the same LDO, MCP1700, it was outputting 3.3V.

I thought that I probably shorted something when I soldered it onto my PIR board. So I soldered it again, and inserted the battery, everything went fine. I just had to clean up some solder point, so I removed the battery, and reinserted it a few minutes later, and AGAIN the MCP1700 burnt!

I don't understand what is going on. Why is the DW06D in place burning my MCP1700 on my board! Please help!

[image: Schematic]

---

**Update 1:**

I added a picture of the tiny board I used for testing, but please remember, the DW06D chip also worked shortly on my actual board.

The short while it did work on the actual board, before removing and replacing the battery, I checked the input and output voltages to the LDO, all was fine.

The two holes on the board are just going to the 18650 battery holder on the back.

Oh and please disregard the capacitor on the tiny test board :)

[image: The Actual Board which I want to get to work]

[image: Zoom of Actual Board with DW06D in place, and burnt MCP1700]

Comment: Could this be relevant:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/475575 ? If so, how?

Comment: Are you using proper antistatic handling when you insert the battery?

Comment: @CenTinel - Hi, I don't see how your case can be exactly the same as the one in that link (fake regulators), since your regulator worked before adding the DW06D and in the linked case, they didn't ever work as expected. You said that you "*made a small board to test the DW06D*". Can you edit the question and add a photo of your actual prototype hardware configuration, showing all wiring? If the DW06D is on a separate board (which is not obvious from the schematic) that could be relevant. Also, do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Hi, the link I meant as relevant is not regarding a fake batch. If you click on the link you are taken to the exact answer. I will post a picture in the morning and unfortunately I do not have an oscilloscope

Comment: @CenTinel - Hi, OK, I understand and yes, the wiring inductance mentioned in that specific answer (even though it wasn't the accepted answer in that case) is the same reason I'm asking to see the physical layout & inter-board wiring. Your schematic doesn't show the DW06D on a *separate* PCB, but your question mentions a "*small board to test the DW06D*" so I thought pictures would make it easier for members to understand the physical construction / wiring. Unfortunately, without an oscilloscope, there may be some guesswork next :-( Perhaps members here will spot something in the photos.

Comment: @CenTinel - Thanks for the update. (a) So that little board is not for the DW06D (no other device was mentioned), but for the DW06D **and** the MCP1700 (now in TO-92)! That new info removes my concern about the use of long wires between the DW06D and the MCP1700, and the effect of wiring inductance when the DW06D switches the Gnd connection. (b) Can you link to an English-language datasheet for the DW06D? (c) In your position, I would be analysing the DW06D behaviour with a scope, but you don't have one :-( (d) Little board seems to have no S2 connection to DW06D or to one end of new cap?

Comment: After I burnt the first MCP1700, on my Actual PIR board, I just wanted to test whats going on so I made the little board. The fried chips occurred on the PIR board. I had the same problem, I cannot find any english language datasheet on the DW06D. But pinwise, it seems to be the same as a DW01. Please disregard the little board. I removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @CenTinel - This is probably my last comment :-( (No scope traces, no English language datasheet, and my main area of concern has been resolved.) Personally I *would* continue working with the little board, instead of disregarding it! (In troubleshooting terms, it could be called a "minimal test case" and is often helpful.). MCP1700 requires i/p **and** o/p caps *close* to it (on your main board, they both seem to be there, but could be closer to the regulator). I would use the small board, add both caps very close to the MCP1700 (and a load resistor) and see if behaviour improves. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try that. Could you maybe recommend another chip instead of the DW06D which would protect the 18650. Short circuit, excessive drain...

Answer (score 1):

The different packages have different pin-outs that makes it very confusing.

[image: MCP1700]

Comment: Yeh, sorry about that, its the SOT-23

Answer (score 0):

You have the 4.2V battery connected to pin 3 which is not the input of the LDO, it is its output. Look at the datasheet of the LDO.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/m4XDgDX/Screen-Shot-2021-02-06-at-03-28-37.png

Its correct.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the choose, in your schematic the Point (indicating Pin 1) with U1 is not correct. It should be with V- and not with S2. In consequence V- and S2 are swapped in function.

Please give a little feedback, if happy end is reached.